# Oracle 11g Pivot Distinct Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, distinct, pivot

I have data like this:

```
**ATTR_ID**    **ATTR_VAL**
103            E
104            F             
136            E
136            U
```

I want to transform the data into this using PIVOT:

```
**103**     **104**     **136**
E           F           U
E           F           E
```

Using MAX() in the PIVOT produces one record.  I need to get both records.  An attribute id can have multiple attribute values.

```
SELECT *
( SELECT ATTR_ID, ATTR_VAL FROM DATA_TABLE )
PIVOT (MAX(ATTR_VAL) FOR ATTR_ID IN (103,104,136))
```

Am I going about this wrong using PIVOT?

Comment: Why is there a second E for 103 and a second F for 104?  That data doesn't appear in your sample.  Are you just copying it down?  If 104 and 136 both had two rows in the table, how do you know which rows go together in the pivoted output?  Or doesn't it matter?  If 104 had 3 rows, how do you know whether to copy the U or the E from 136 down?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You're right the data does not appear in the sample but I have to create it.  Another developer explained it me that I need to create the "cartesian product". All of the data is stored in nested rows.  I have to change the rows back into columns so that I can join to another table.  Does that give you more insight to the issue?

Comment: So, if you want a Cartesian product, that would mean if there were 2 rows for 103, 3 rows for 104, and 5 rows for 136, you'd end up with 2*3*5 = 30 rows.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would get 30 rows following that scenario. Can a pivot produce a cartesian product?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a Cartesian product

```
SELECT attr_103.attr_val as "103",
       attr_104.attr_val as "104",
       attr_136.attr_val as "136"
  FROM (SELECT attr_id, attr_val
          FROM attr_table
         WHERE attr_id = 103) attr_103
       CROSS JOIN 
       (SELECT attr_id, attr_val
          FROM attr_table
         WHERE attr_id = 104) attr_104
       CROSS JOIN 
       (SELECT attr_id, attr_val
          FROM attr_table
         WHERE attr_id = 136) attr_136
```